# LWJGL 3 OSX -XstartOnFirstThread not working

Tags: scala, sbt, lwjgl

I'm using LWJGL 3 in an SBT based project. I'm developing it on a Mac (El Capitan) but when I run the project I get this error:

```
[error] Caused by: java.lang.IllegalStateException: Please run the JVM with -XstartOnFirstThread.
```

I've tried adding `-XstartOnFirstThread` as a VM option by forking the run and setting it in javaOptions like this:

```
.settings(
  fork in run := true,
  javaOptions in run ++= Seq("-XstartOnFirstThread", "-Djava.library.path=lib")
)
```

but I still get the error. I've also tried running from within IntelliJ but I get the same error even when setting `-XstartOnFirstThread` as a VM Option in the run configuration.

Comment: For anyone else that have similar problem. I made a video about how to set everything on a Mac. Including -XstartOnFirstThread,
-Djava.awt.headless=true and seteing up the pom.xml. https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=98iGmMVKntw

Answer (score 1):

I was creating an instance of a class that took an `java.awt.Color` as a parameter. OSX didn't like that! Removing all references to `Color` has solved the problem.

Why doesn't OSX like `awt`?

Comment: AWT and LWJGL fight for the same thread, ie the first. You can add this VM option -Djava.awt.headless=true